# How can I pass a variable from 'outside' to a react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a react app using `create-react-app my-app`. I have an existing web page, and the react app attaches to a div within the html page - as per normal.

The web page has some global javascript constants `const1` and `const2` that are needed for the react app to function. Is there a way I can pass these variables to the react app? The structure is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const const1 = "1234";
  const const2 = "5678";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src = "/static/react-app.js" ></script>
```

I'm struggling because the javascript is of course minified during the build phase, so any declarations as follows:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stat1: const1,
      stat2: const2,
```

don't work as the variables are re-written. I have tried to be sneaky and use eval as follows

```
const const1 = eval("function c1(){console.log(const1);return const1;};c1();");
```

but the eval (and the console.log) return undefined. Is there a way I can invoke a react component, and pass it variables from the outside?

Comment: Would an environment variable work?

Comment: Ugh! Genius - yes it does work!

Comment: I've included the environment variables and another method as a solution.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I see two options here.

1. Assign the variables to the `window` object
2. Use environment variables

**Using the `window` object**

To use the `window` object, declare the variable as

```
myVar = 'someString'
```

or

```
window.myVar = 'someString'
```

In both cases you'll access the variable within React with `window.myVar`. Here's a quick example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, React and ES6!</h1>
        <p>Let's play. :)</p>
        <p>{window.myVar}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
<script>
  window.myVar = 'someString2'
</script>
```

**Using environment variables**

The Create React App build allows for [environment variables to be used](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) within the app. To add an environment variable create a `.env` file in the root of your project, then add the appropriate variables and prefix the variable name with `REACT_APP_`. For example:

```
REACT_APP_MYVAR = "someString"
```

In the app these variables can be accessed within your components with `{process.env.REACT_APP_MYVAR}`, or within the HTML with `%REACT_APP_MYVAR%`.

Comment: Thanks! I guess the `myVar = 'someString'` is akin to @Petr suggestion to use `var` in ES6?

Comment: For me the window.myVar way doesn't work, React isn't seeing the variable

Comment: This is really good! how about using function from another component?

Comment: @suisied I wrote an article on this awhile back - https://brettdewoody.com/accessing-component-methods-and-state-from-outside-react/

Comment: How can I use Environment variables from a razor generated View (Server is .net core)?

Comment: This work with simple values. Is there any chance to pass a json for example as a parameter to react?

Comment: @nickornotto - yes, you can assign any JS data type your `window` variables.

Answer (score 6):

The EcmaScript 6 introduced block-scope variables and constants declared by `let` resp. `const`.

In contrast to the "old style" declaration of variable by `var` the visibility of such variable resp. constant is limited to actual block.

The scope of constant `const1` (resp. `const2`) is therefore limited only to the code inside the script tag.
To be able to access the `const1` (resp. `const2`) from another script tag you would need to change its visibility. This can be achieved either by declaring it by `var` or by assigning its value to a variable declared by `var`.

E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const const1 = "1234";
  const const2 = "5678";
  var visibleConst1 = const1;
</script>
```

Later in your React application you can read it from `window.visibleConst1`.

Comment: that's pretty powerful - thanks for sharing! I guess at compile time it'll change to becoming a formal environment (so `window.visibleConst1 = const1`) variable to be backwards compatible?